# Passing constructor parameters to a template function factory

Tags: c++, templates

I have this function:

```
template <class T> 
T *allocate()
{
    T *obj = new(top) T();
    top += sizeof(T);
    return obj;
}
```

Now, it's working great creating objects with default constructors but how do I create objects who need to be passed new parameters?

I know it can be achieved using C++11's variadic `template`s but how can I do this without C++11 functionality? (Apparently my version of VS2012 don't support this feature yet, but I would like to know how to do this without this feature even if an upgrade will fix it)

Comment: You can emulate variadic templates using many overloads for 0, 1, 2, ... N parameters. Boost.Preprocesser can be used to generate them.

Comment: You may try to implement it with a C macro, though it's *dangerous* and not encouraged by most C++ guide

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't a language feature that replaces variadic templates (of course, otherwise they wouldn't have been invented).

You can provide several overloads that accept up to `N` parameters (for a reasonable choice of `N`). Each overload would perfect-forward its argument to the constructor of `T`.

So apart from your nullary function template:

```
template <class T>
T *allocate()
{
    T *obj = new(top) T();
    top += sizeof(T);
    return obj;
}
```

You will have a unary function template:

```
template <class T, class P1>
T *allocate(P1&& p1)
{
    T *obj = new(top) T(std::forward<P1>(p1));
    top += sizeof(T);
    return obj;
}
```

A binary function template:

```
template <class T, class P1, class P2>
T *allocate(P1&& p1, P2&& p2)
{
    T *obj = new(top) T(std::forward<P1>(p1), std::forward<P2>(p2));
    top += sizeof(T);
    return obj;
}
```

A ternary function template:

```
template <class T, class P1, class P2, class P3>
T *allocate(P1&& p1, P2&& p2, P3&& p3)
{
    T *obj = new(top) T(std::forward<P1>(p1), std::forward<P2>(p2), 
                        std::forward<P3>(p3));
    top += sizeof(T);
    return obj;
}
```

And so on (you get the point). If you mind the code replication, you can figure out some macros that would reduce the pain - but they do not eliminate it, especially if you are not fond of macros.

Don't forget to:

```
#include <utility>
```

To have access to `std::forward<>()`.

Comment: Isn't `std::forward` part of C++11? The OP was asking how to do it without C++11 functionality.

Comment: @zindorsky: I think the OP is interested in features supported by VC11. Perfect forwarding is supported

Answer (score 1):

It's not just the variadic templates that you need, but also C++11's perfect forwarding capabilities.

If you don't have C++11 functionality, it is possible to fake it, at least for a set limit to the number of parameters. But it isn't easy or pretty. For an example, see the boost implementation of `boost::tuple`.

Answer (score 1):

If you ca use boost, you could use `boost::in_place_factory` instead http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/libs/utility/in_place_factories.html

```
template <class InplaceFactory> 
T *allocate(InplaceFactory const & fac)
{
    T *obj = reinterpret_cast<T*>(top);
    fac.template apply<T>(obj)
    top += sizeof(T);
    return obj;
}
```

And use:

```
T * a = allocate(boost::in_place(val, boost::ref(ref_value)));
```

**PS**
Not to do so:

```
T * a = allocate(boost::in_place());
```

You can add overload:

```
T *allocate(){ return allocate(boost::in_place()); }
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have to take a design hit on this one if you don't want to use varadic template:

```
struct empty {};
template<typename ObjectType,unsigned int ARG_LENGTH = 0,
         typename arg0=empty,
         typename arg1=empty,
         typename arg2=empty,
         typename arg3=empty,
         typename arg4=empty>
ObjectType* allocate(const arg0& a0, 
                     const arg1& a1,
                     const arg2& a2,
                     const arg3& a3,
                     const arg4& a4){
   ObjectType * obj = 0;
   switch(ARG_LENGTH){
     case 0: obj = new(top) ObjectType();break;
     case 1: obj = new(top) ObjectType(arg0);break;
     case 2: obj = new(top) ObjectType(arg0,arg1);break;
     case 3: obj = new(top) ObjectType(arg0,arg1,arg2);break;
     case 4: obj = new(top) ObjectType(arg0,arg1,arg2,arg3); break;
     default: obj = new(top) ObjectType(); break;
   }
   top += sizeof(T);
   return obj;
}
```

Not sure if that will compile but you get the idea.